# Angular access Directive-Controller Variables inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

I don't want to post too much Code here, I am currently just struggling with something basic.

I have a directive restricted as attribute:

```
export class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    bindToController = true;
    controller = MyDirectiveController;
    controllerAs = "vm";
    restrict = "A";
    scope = true;
    constructor(){

    };
}
```

The Controller looks like this:

```
export interface IMyDirectiveScope{
    isTrue:boolean;
}

 export class MyDirectiveController implements IMyDirectiveScope{
    public isTrue:boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.isTrue = false;
    }
}
```

Now what I basically want, is to access the `isTrue` variable. Nothing more.

So here is my HTML, where I want to do this:

```
<div my-directive>
    <ul>
        <button type="button" ng-click="vm.isTrue = !vm.isTrue"></button>
     </ul>
    <some-other-directive ng-show="vm.isTrue"></some-other-directive>
</div>
```

Just for some background-info, I want to toggle the `some-other-directive` which is kind of a sidemenu. Inside this I will do a require, where I will fetch the MyDirectiveController to also access the `isTrue` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you are almost there. There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PNugz8rD4ot9PBIW7V0c?p=preview)

I just adjusted a it your TS definitions:

```
namespace MyStuff {
  export interface IMyDirectiveScope{
    isTrue:boolean;
  }

  export class MyDirectiveController implements IMyDirectiveScope{
    public isTrue:boolean = false;
    public title: string = "the directive title";
  }

  export class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    bindToController = true;
    controller = MyDirectiveController;
    controllerAs = "vm";
    restrict = "A";
    scope = true;
  }

  var app = angular.module('MyApp');

  app.directive("myDirective", () => new MyDirective());
}
```

and this template is working:

```
<div my-directive> 
    title: <var>{{vm.title}}</var> - isTrue: <var>{{vm.isTrue}}</var>
    <ul>
        <button type="button" ng-click="vm.isTrue = !vm.isTrue">click it</button>
     </ul>
    <h2 ng-show="vm.isTrue">{{vm.title}}</h2>
</div>
```

The `vm` is now available and can be used to access properties like `title` or `isTrue`.

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PNugz8rD4ot9PBIW7V0c?p=preview)